# Laravel joining table with relation model return as json

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables:

- `products` table (`id`, `name`)
- `ingredients` table (`id`, `ingredient_name`)
- `products_ingredients` table (`product_id`, `ingredient_id`)

I have a relation defined in Product

```
public function ingredients(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductIngredient','product_id','id');
}
```

When I am listing products using

```
$products = Product::where('category_id',$cat->id)->with('ingredients')->get();
```

I am getting this output

```
"products": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hesp",
    "category_id": 1,
    "ingredients": [{
        "id": 41,
        "product_id": 1,
        "ingredient_id": 4,
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "product_id": 1,
        "ingredient_id": 5,
    }]
}]
```

Which is right.

What I want is to add the ingredient name in ingredients list like this

```
"products": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hesp",
    "category_id": 1,
    "ingredients": [{
        "id": 41,
        "product_id": 1,
        "ingredient_id": 4,
        "ingredient_name": "some name" // I want to add this field
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "product_id": 1,
        "ingredient_id": 5,
        "ingredient_name": "some name" // I want to add this field 
    }]
}]
```

I want to return this as JSON to use in API not in blade where I can call other relations.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't see that you have the ingredient_name field in your ingredients table. Add it and you should get it returned in the payload.

Comment: Table two: ingredients field: id, ingredient_name

Comment: I have added ingerdient_name. Now what would be the query ?

Comment: Include your Ingredient->Product relation as well

Comment: @miken There relation is already there. How get the output as desired.

Comment: You included Product->Ingredients relation in your question, not other way around. Anyway my answer will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented the many-to-many relationship all wrong. Per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> Many-to-many relationships are defined by writing a method that returns the result of the belongsToMany method.
>
> ...
>
> To define the inverse of a many-to-many relationship, you place another call to belongsToMany on your related model.

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient', 'products_ingredients');
    }
}

class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'products_ingredients');
    }
}
```

Note the related model is first argument to `belongsToMany()`. It's not needed to create a model for a simple pivot table. Because you have misnamed the pivot table, it must be specified as the second argument to the `belongsToMany()`. The default name is singular model in alphabetic order, i.e. `ingredient_product`.

---

Your output should look something like this now, including the values from the `ingredients` table, not the pivot table.

```
"products": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hesp",
    "category_id": 1,
    "ingredients": [{
        "id": 4,
        "ingredient_name": "some name"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "ingredient_name": "some name"
    }]
}]
```